# java Map.Entry<Long, Long> abc.getkey() returns string in run time

Tags: java

I have a Map like `Map<Long, Long> serials`
I want to iterate it in a for loop.
My code is

```
for (Map.Entry<Long, Long> serial : serials.entrySet()) {
   custOrder = get(serial.getKey());
}
```

Where the `get()` method take a Long.

It's compile with no error. But in run time `serial.getKey()` returns a String.

Comment: This makes no sense, if `serial.getKey()` returns a `String`, your code shouldn't pass compilation (unless you are using a raw `Map` type in the declaration of `serials`).

Comment: That means you used the map as a raw type somewhere in your code, or used reflection to populate it. Don't do that. Or at least, if using reflection, well, fix it.

Comment: Where is your `Map<Long, Long> serials` initialization?

Comment: How can you sure about "But in run time `serial.getKey()` returns a String."?

Comment: Paste the output of  ```serial.getKey().getClass()```

Comment: @JBNizet This code is in a method `saveVPSerials(Map<Long, Long> serials)` where `serials` is a parameter. How can I do this without row map type

Comment: The problematic code (if the key is really a string), is elsewhere. You're putting strings somehow in this map. We can't explain with the code you posted. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it